# Creating structs with loop - VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to loop through a table and create an instance of a struct for every row. The issue I'm running into is naming each struct differently. This is what I have so far. I haven't initiated the individual structs yet cause I'm stuck on naming them differently... What's the way to do this?

```
Public Type Suggestion

    Person As String
    Suspect As String
    Weapon As String
    Room As String
    Refuted As String
    Card As String
    
End Type

Do While Application.WorksheetFunction.IsText(CCell)
    Dim Name As String
    Name = "Suggestion" & CStr(NSelections + 1)
    Dim Name As Suggestion
    //Initiate struct instance
    NSelections = NSelections + 1
    CCell = Cells(3 + NSelections, 9)
Loop
```

Comment: When you `Dim Name As Suggestion` you just overwrite what you just populated in that variable.  If you want to refer to your structs by name then consider storing them in a Dictionary

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, your intention isn't entirely clear. However, the code below will set you on the right path. Please try it.

```
Public Type Suggestion
    Person As String
    Suspect As String
    Weapon As String
    Room As String
    Refuted As String
    Card As String
End Type

Sub Macro()

    Dim Temp    As Suggestion   ' instance of 'Suggestion' type
    Dim R       As Long         ' loop counter: rows
    
    For R = 2 To Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
        With Temp
            .Person = Cells(R, 1).Value
            .Suspect = Cells(R, 2).Value
            .Weapon = Cells(R, 3).Value
            .Room = Cells(R, 4).Value
            .Refuted = Cells(R, 5).Value
            .Card = Cells(R, 6).Value
        End With
    Next R
    
    With Temp
        MsgBox .Person & vbCr & _
               .Suspect & vbCr & _
               .Weapon & vbCr & _
               .Room & vbCr & _
               .Refuted & vbCr & _
               .Card
    End With
End Sub
```

The purpose of my code is to demonstrate how to use the `Type` you created. It shows you how to assign a value from a worksheet to each member of the `Type`. Then it shows you how to retrieve the assigned values.

For the rest of it it doesn't make sense because there is only a single instance of the variable `Temp`. The data from each row are written to it, each new row over-writing the previous, so that in the end only the data from the last row are retained. Now, you could create an array, like Temp(10), assign a different instance of `Suggestion` to each element and recall members with syntax like *Temp(2).Person*. That's work perfectly well but the question is what to do with that. You might be better off using the table or an array into which the table is copied. The `Type` data type may not be the most efficient way of handling the data where you want everything in memory.

I've never had the opportunity to use a `Type` in my projects. But I imagine its best use would be to hold a single data set, just as demonstrated in the above code. Instead of creating many instances of `Temp`, look for the raw that you want and assign data from that one row to `Temp`. Then, if you want another instance, create it for the next occasion.